# Sketchup Follow Me tool is removing geometry instead of adding it

Tags: sketchup

I've followed several YouTube videos, step by step, and whenever they click the face of the path to follow, then click the Follow Me tool, then click the face they want to extrude, they get a beautiful path. Whenever I do it, it just removes geometry from my model instead of adding. I took a video and converted it to a gif below to show you what I mean.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: animated gif showing the problem]

Answer (score 0):

Select the Edge, then go to follow me and at last hit the profile.

Thank you.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've tried selecting the face and selecting just the edge and I still get the same failure. It doesn't produce for me what it producing for you. What am I doing wrong? I'll update my post above with another gif.

Comment: Kindly clean up the file. (last attached image). sometimes invisible geometry creates problems. or open a new file and try from scratch. Its very simple. I hope You will succeed.

Comment: I've tried repeatedly starting from scratch. I start from an empty file, create a circle, create an arc, try to follow me and it doesn't work. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I wasn't able to post a new gif because it was too big, here is a YT video: https://youtu.be/GpMO_yl4wbs

Comment: I've been using SketchUp for years, so I'm not brand new or anything, but I've just never really gotten the Follow Me tool to work for me and I don't know why.

Comment: I tried what that YT video showed. mine works. 

Oh Okay. I am sorry. I thought you are newbie. I dnt know why it dsnt work for you :(

Comment: You can try sketch up community. post this in a detailed form.  Some modifiers in 3ds max sometimes behave like this. no explanation why do they act so idiot. 

software related community sort things like magic. OR YOU CAN WAIT HERE . May some one have solution of this problem.